# Subset dataframe by row values of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

i am trying to subset a dataframe with extracted data from another dataframe. My data looks essentially like this:

```
PriceData

Date          AAPL   BAC   CAT    JNJ    PG    UNH   VZ
2004-04-26     
2004-04-27            Daily Prices
2004-04-28     
2004-04-29     


Companies

Date          X1     X2     X3    X4
2004-04-26   AAPL   CAT     PG    VZ
2004-04-27   AAPL   CAT     UNH   VZ
2004-04-28   AAPL   JNJ     UNH   VZ
2004-04-29   AAPL   JNJ     UNH   VZ
```

I have already managed to subset the `Companies` dataframe by date, so i have a dataframe with one row containing the tickers of a specific date. For instance:

```
Tickers
Date          X1     X2    X3    X4
2004-04-28    AAPL   JNJ   UNH   VZ
```

What i would like to do now is to subset the `PriceData` dataframe so that only the price data of the four tickers in `Tickers` remain:

```
newPriceData

Date          AAPL    JNJ    UNH    VZ
2004-04-26
2004-04-27        Daily Prices
2004-04-28
2004-04-29
```

Does anybody know what package/function i could use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R, data.table, and dplyr solutions. data.table and dplyr are packages which provide alternative functions for data manipulation. I encourage you to look into both -- each is much more flexible and convenient than base R subsetting. You can find the CRAN pages [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html). They each have a vignette (tutorial) listed as "Introduction to ".

Below I've listed a corresponding command for each. For dplyr and data.table, there are slight variations of those listed which might be considered more natural for dplyr or data.table, but these contain the smallest diversions from a similarity to base syntax.

```r
columns_to_retain <- unlist(Tickers[1,-1]) # Take the first row, drop the first column, convert to plain vector.
NewPriceData <- PriceData[,columns_to_retain]

# dplyr
library(dplyr)
NewPriceData <- select(PriceData, columns_to_retain) # or names(Tickers) instead of columns_to_retain

# data.table
NewPriceData <- PriceData[,columns_to_retain, with = FALSE]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When i use names(Tickers) it gives me X1,X2,X3,X4. However i would like to subset PriceData by the tickers corresponding to X1...X4, which are AAPL, JNJ, UNH and VZ. Whatever i try, i always get the colnames out of it and not the values from Tickers.

Comment: Sorry for missing that key piece. I've updated my answer

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much, i greatly appreciate it.